# Isolate characters from string

Tags: c#, .net, string, character

So I have a string called today with the value "*nick*_george_*james*"
it looks like this

```
string today = "_nick__george__james_";
```

how can i isolate the text between the '_' into a new string? i want to get the 3 names into seperate strings so that in the end i have name1, name2, name3 with the values nick, george and james

my application is written in c#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

```
string[] array = today.Split('_');
```

After editing your question, I realized that you have multiple `_` in your string. You should try the following.

```
string[] array = today.Split("_".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Or

```
string[] array = today.Split(new []{"_"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Later your `array` will contain:

```
array[0] = "nick";
array[1] = "george";
array[2] = "james";
```

Comment: Might want to call the overload with StringSplitOptions to specify RemoveEmptyEntries.

Comment: @TylerOhlsen, just edited my answer to post the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] array = today.Split('_');
name1=array[0];
name2=array[1];
name3=array[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] nameArray = today.Split('_');
```

Here you will get a array of names. You can get each name from by specifying index positions of the nameArray.

ie Now the the nameArray contains values as below

nameArray[0] = "nick", nameArray[1] = "george", nameArray[2] = "james"

Answer (score 0):

***Thought of coming up with an idea other than string.Split.***

```
string today = "_nick__george__james_";

//Change value nNoofwordstobeFound  accordingly

int nNoofwordstobeFound = 3;
int nstartindex = 0;
int nEndindex = 0;
int i=1;
while (i <= nNoofwordstobeFound)
{
    Skip:
    nstartindex = today.IndexOf("_",nEndindex);
    nEndindex = today.IndexOf("_", nstartindex + 1);

    string sName = today.Substring(nstartindex + 1, nEndindex - (nstartindex + 1));
    if (sName == "")
    {
        goto Skip;
    }
    else
    {
        //Do your code
        //For example                 
        string abc=  sName;    
    }

    i++;
}
```

I'd still prefer string.split method over this anytime.

Comment: Use 'break;' instead of goto.  Though the idea of writing your own split is silly regardless